# AS2 Connection via PI

Tags: actionscript-2

I want to create an AS2 connection with my customer by using SAP PI tool. But PI is in internal network. We also have a DMZ machine. How can I make the AS2 connection between each other ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar integration.

We use Run Operation System command After message Processing, under the processing tab in communication channel (file).

Basicaly: write the file on the internal network with the file communicaiton channel that then launch a SH (or BAT) script launching the AS2 transfert to the outside.
Hope it can help. We have multiple integrations using this on i5/OS and Windows.

Regards,
M

Edit: added the proper CC's option name